# How to start/stop a website in IIS using c++

Tags: c++, iis-7.5

I am using IIS 7.5 in windows 7 machine.

I need to start/stop websites from my C++ application. This is a plain win32 app, nothing to do with .NET.

Now, I've found out how to configure websites, using the **IAppHostAdministration** interfaces as mentioned in the link https://forums.iis.net/t/1146649.aspx.

With IIS 7, my code does this:

- Get the AppHostWritableAdminManager and commit the path
  MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site/.
- Call GetAdminSection with the section name appSettings.
- Then look at the returned collection and creating new site using
  CreateNewElement method.

But I can't find a way to start/stop those websites.
Please help me.

Comment: IAppHostAdministration has 3 Google hits, one being your question and another the forum link you included. You really want a MSDN-documented interface.

Comment: @MSalters I want to execute appcmd start sites "site1" using c++ for starting the website. How to achieve it?

Comment: No idea. I thought that I'd Google `IAppHostAdministration` to see if I could answer the question using MSDN, but that didn't help at all. If I knew the answer, I'd written it in the answer field. I added a comment to point out to other people that `IAppHostAdministration` is a red herring.